# Dual boot Win 11 & Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bios, multi-boot, windows-11, dell-vostro

Does my PC (https://www.dell.com/en-uk/shop/laptop-computers-2-in-1-pcs/vostro-3525/spd/vostro-15-3525-laptop) support dual booting Win 11 and Ubuntu. I tried several times and followed the instructions as given on https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-uk/000131253/how-to-install-ubuntu-and-windows-8-or-10-as-a-dual-boot-on-your-dell-pc. It doesn't recognise my USB and goes to Win 11 login screen. Can you please help how to dual boot. I don't want to use VM bcos when using VM the total RAM usage is hitting 13 GB (8 gb for VM) unnecessarily.

Also any pointers on Virtualization settings in BIOS and I don't see it in my BIOS(https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-uk/000195978/how-to-enable-or-disable-hardware-virtualization-on-dell-systems?lang=en).

However Virtualisation has been existing since Sandy Bridge(2012) and now being 2022 I don't understand why its not enabled in BIOS by default. Please provide some pointers.

Regards,

Aditya

Comment: Dual booting doesn't rely on virtualization. If you boot the system with your Linux USB installer connected and start tapping F12 you should get into Boot Order -screen where you can choose which device to boot from.

Comment: Unless you have a heavy duty use for Ubuntu, you are far better off to make an Ubuntu Virtual Machine. Safer for the Windows 11 Host machine.

Comment: There's  no reason to avoid dual booting, other than the extra space taken up by Windows 11. Of six machines I maintain, two are dual-boot, with no issues, and the other four Linux, also working well. Just don't write to the Windows partition if "dirty', e.g. has *hiberfil.sys*.